# Select the opposite row of a WHERE clause in a joined jquery result

Tags: mysql

I have a database with users and games. 1 game can have multiple users so I made a linking table called users_games. The crux is that a game can always only have 2 players since it is a board game. I know which player I am, i have my user_id and my email, but I would like to gain a result that gives me a list of all games I am in WITH the user_id and email of the other fellow. So a query that looks to all games I am in and give the other row, with the name of the player.

My tables:

**games**

```
id (int)
board (varchar) representation of the board
```

**users**

```
id (int)
email (varchar)
password (varchar MD5)
```

**users_games**

```
id (int)
user_id (int)
game_id (int)
```

For clarification this query

```
SELECT * 
        FROM `tic_users_games` AS ug 
        LEFT JOIN tic_users AS u
        ON ug.user_id = u.id
        RIGHT JOIN tic_games AS g
        ON ug.game_id = g.id
```

And result

```
id  user_id     game_id     id  email   password    id  board   created     updated 

1   1   1   1   ME@gmail.com    d56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da    1   0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0   2012-04-02 16:56:06     2012-04-02 16:56:06
2   2   1   2   FOE1@gmail.com  d56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da    1   0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0   2012-04-02 16:56:06     2012-04-02 16:56:06
3   3   2   2   FOE2@gmail.com  d56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da    2   0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0   2012-04-02 16:56:06     2012-04-02 16:56:06
4   1   2   1   ME@gmail.com    d56b699830e77ba53855679cb1d252da    2   0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0   2012-04-02 16:56:06     2012-04-02 16:56:06
```

See: In the above case I just want 2 rows: game_id 1 and 2, with FOE1@... and FOE2@...

Thanks

Comment: Just a minor thing, but shouldn't `FOE2@gmail.com` have a different `user_id`, like `3`?  Here's a schema setup that you can test with: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b0f6

Comment: You are right mate... I changed the emailaddresses for privacy purposes. Gr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you. The syntax might not be exact for mysql but you should get there. Basically get all users that have games in the user_games table with the same game_ID as the games I am in:

```
SELECT
    User_Games.Game_ID,
    Users.ID,
    Users.Email
FROM
    Users 
    LEFT JOIN User_Games ON Users.ID = User_Games.User_Id
WHERE
    Users.User_ID <> @yourUserID
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        User_Games AS MyUserGames
    WHERE
        User_Games.Game_ID = MyUserGames.Game_ID
    AND MyUserGames.User_ID = @yourUserID)
```

Comment: I think you also need `AND Users.id <> @yourUserID` at the end to filter out the current user: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b0f6/7

Answer (score 2):

Try this (where `@userid` represents the user you are searching games for, in this case, 1):

```
    select *
      from tic_users_games ug1
 left join tic_users_games ug2 on ug1.game_id = ug2.game_id
 left join tic_users u         on ug2.user_id = u.id
right join tic_games g         on ug2.game_id = g.id
     where ug1.user_id = @userid
       and ug2.user_id <> @userid
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b0f6/2

Comment: Heya mate, this seems to work indeed. Im not really sure what your idea behind the 2 ug2's is? It works amazing but its a bit unclear to me, could you please elaborate? And amazing job on the fiddles!!

Comment: @HansWassink - The user_games table has 2 rows per game, 1 for Me and 1 for Him. When you join on itself based on game_id this gives 4 rows. MeMe, MeHim, HimMe, HimHim. Look at the where clause. First clause states only rows from the first user_games where I'm the user. This leaves MeMe and MeHim only. Then the second where clause removes rows when I'm in the right table, removing MeMe. This leaves just the row containing MeHim, with Him's details in ug2. Then join this onto users for his user details, finally onto games for game details. A very nice idea.

Comment: @Tobsey: Good explanation :)  Comparing the execution plans, your method looks to be a little more efficient.

Comment: @Tobsey Thanks for the explanation... Im going to hand you the victory here. Both solutions work flawless, but you're the underdog pointwise, and as Mella points out: your's appears a little more efficient!

Comment: @mellamokb SUPER Thanks tho, especially for the fiddles and for your insightful answer!

Comment: @HansWassink: no problem, glad you've found a solution :)